# Change name for multiple functions when calling .agg using a dict

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

Having a dataframe `df` with the columns `id`,`price` and `units` like so

```py
id | price | units
---+-------+--------
1  | 10    | 1
1  | 15    | 4
1  | 13    | 3
2  | 5     | 12
2  | 1     | 20
```

I can apply multiple functions to specific columns like

```py
df.groupby("id").agg({"price":["mean","max"], "units":["mean","max"])
```

Since we have `max` and `mean` twice, it might be nice to rename them (I am aware that the output is a multicolumn-index) to be able to tell the difference.

Normally when using `.agg` we can specify the name like `df.groupby("id")["price"](max_price="max")` but it does not seem to work the same way when parsing a dict e.g

```py
df.groupby("id").agg({"price":[(mean_price="mean"),(max_price="max")],
 "units":[(mean_unit="mean"),(max_unit="max")]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use named aggregation - there is format different - `new column name` with tuples for `columns name` with `aggregation function`:

```
df1 = (df.groupby("id").agg(mean_price= ("price","mean"),
                            max_price=("price","max"),
                            mean_unit=("units","mean"),
                            max_unit=("units","max")))
print (df1)
    mean_price  max_price  mean_unit  max_unit
id                                            
1    12.666667         15   2.666667         4
2     3.000000          5  16.000000        20
```

Another solution if want pass dictionary is use dict with `**` for unpacking arguments:

```
df1 = (df.groupby("id").agg(**{'mean_price':("price","mean"),
                               'max_price':("price","max"),
                               'mean_unit':("units","mean"),
                               'max_unit':("units","max")}))
```

Comment: Or using `pd.NamedAgg` except for readability there's no advantage.

Comment: @Ch3steR - and more typing ;)